# How do you say "I'm glad to hear from you"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, conjugaison

When I call my friend on the phone, I would like to know how to say "I'm glad to hear from you" in French.

My online sources only show the formal way of speaking ("Je suis contente de vous entendre"), but I would like to know the informal way.

Would "Je suis contente de t'entendre" be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on the phone, you can also say : *je suis content de t'avoir au bout du fil*.

*Au bout du fil* is a common phrase that means "on the other end of a phone communication" (and yes, it is  used even if there is no actual "wire" on most phones nowadays).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "Je suis contente de t'entendre" is correct.

Comment: You can also say `Je suis contente d'avoir de tes nouvelles`. Which means the same.